# Bootstrap accordion disable controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using the snippet below to:

- **disable all** :input elements in hidden panels;
- **enable all** :input elements in visible panel (Just one panel can be opened);

  $(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
      $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', false);
  });

  $(".panel").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(e) {
      $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', true);
  });

But it seems to not working right. How can I fix this? Thanks!
P.S: All panels are hidden after page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `attr()` with `prop()`. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$(".panel").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
});

$(".panel").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(e) {
    $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
});
```